# Why is Visual Studio 2008 slow with Firefox?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, firefox, visual-studio-express

- I am using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 Express.
- I've made an ASP.NET MVC site which has 6 CSS files and 6 Javascript files in the HEAD element in the Site.Master file.
- When I do F5 or CTRL-F5 in Explorer or Opera, the site displays instantly.
- When I run my site in Firefox, it takes a SECOND for each CSS and each Javascript file on LOCALHOST, i.e. 12 seconds to load on localhost.

What might I be able to change in the Firefox settings so it is as fast as Opera and Explorer?

NEW INFO:
Uninstalled Firebug completely, no yslow, no other add-ons. When I take out the CSS and Javascript files, then Firefox is as fast as the other browsers. What could be taking it so long on a local connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be related to IPv6 as explained in [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/06/17/fixing-firefox-slowness-with-localhost-on-vista.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Set *localhost* to use IPv4 only (or disable IPv6 for all sites):

1. Type *`about:config`* in the address bar
2. Find *`ipv4`* section
3. Set *`network.dns.ipv4OnlyDomains =`*`localhost`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an add-on.  Are you running anything like YSlow or Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

my firefox behaving the same way, in the OLD VS, they put the debugging thing in services in control panel, but now i cant find it anywhere.